# Date and Time Format/Patterns in java / SimpleDateFormat class

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to format a date using the method where `dd-mm-YYYY` is an example date

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
cal.setTimeInMillis(displayDate*1000);
String date = DateFormat.format("dd-mm-YYYY", cal).toString();
```

I'm looking for a list of characters I can use, similar to [this in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), to format my date how I want. Is there a list anywhere around I can use? The format I'm after is `26th April, 2006`, but a list would be good so I could bookmark it for reference later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaDoc of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) does contain such a list.

[image]

Comment: That's just what I was after, thanks :). (I'll accept in 3 mins when SO let's me)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's in the javadoc for SimpleDateFormat:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/